# WCF message too big even with correct web.config

Tags: c#, wcf, http, web-config, basichttpbinding

I have a WCF service with the following web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MetadataExchange">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LargeHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="5064536" maxBufferPoolSize="5064536" maxReceivedMessageSize="5064536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5064536" maxArrayLength="5064536" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MetadataExchange" name="Service.Interface.ApplicationService.ApplicationService">
        <endpoint name="httpEndpoint" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeHttpBinding" contract="Service.Proxy.ApplicationService.Interfaces.IApplicationService" />
        <endpoint name="mexEndpoint" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:15000/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="httpEndpoint" address="http://localhost:15000/ApplicationService/ApplicationService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeHttpBinding" contract="Service.Proxy.ApplicationService.Interfaces.IApplicationService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <!--ToDo: Set directory browse to false-->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The service should be able to receive 5MB+Overhead messages (I send pictures as byte arrays to the server).

On the client side I use a ChannelFactory with the following BasicHttpBinding:

```
basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
basicHttpBinding.MaxBufferSize = 5064536;
basicHttpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 5064536;
basicHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 5064536;
basicHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
basicHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 5064536;
basicHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 5064536;
basicHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 4096;
basicHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384;
```

If I try to send pictures with a size of about 150kb an error message is thrown with the following message:

> The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.

Comment: I am an idiot!
The size of the test picture was just too big... It had a dimension of 1920*1080 and a size of 167kb. But if i converted it to a byte array it had a size of 8 MB because 2,073,600 pixels multiplied by 4 (a, r, g, b)...

Should i delete this question?